# Always sort Recent Places by date modifed

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

I used to always have the Recent Places shortcut folder sorted by date modified (which is the only reasonable way to sort it). But some time ago it started sorting it by name automatically. No matter what I try it seems that I can never get it to remember to sort by date. Even if I click the Date Modified column header, then navigate to another folder and then come back it is sorted by name again! No other folder behaves like this. Do other people have this problem? Any way to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-desktop/how-to-set-default-sort-order-in-recent-places/062975af-db40-4a3b-882e-f84f28c1c6bd) worked for me:

> Thanks.  That didn't work as easily as explained. 
>   When I open Windows Explorer and select the sort order, it does not make that selection the default sort order.
>   But I just found out that if I open my Personal Folder, then select Recent Places and then set the sort order (and make it he default in folder options), it will make the selection the default.

Comment: Please attribute and link to the source if you're taking quotes from another site. http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-desktop/how-to-set-default-sort-order-in-recent-places/062975af-db40-4a3b-882e-f84f28c1c6bd

Comment: Does this mean select Recent Places inside my user folder? Because I don't see Recent places in there. If I simply click on my user folder and then click on Recent Places in the Favorites section and go to folder options I am not able to apply the current view to all similar folders (the button is greyed out).

Comment: However, I read the linked thread and the last poster said to try sorting by type first, then date. And so far that seems to have done the trick!...

Answer (score 1):

Go to Folder Options then Reset Folders. Sort by date modified and this should work. (It worked for me).

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 7 Windows Explorer>Organize>FolderAndSearchOptions>View>ResetFolders>OK.

Then go to "Recent Places", click "Date Modified" to sort by date modified. Close and open Recent Places again, and the setting persists.